# Heroku Postgres FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Trying to run postgres database with Django application on heroku, but I've met strange issue 'FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections'. When I look to `pg:info`, it shows

```
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 1/20
PG Version:  9.4.1
Created:     2015-08-07 13:30 UTC
Data Size:   6.6 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance) - refreshing
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
Region:      Europe
Add-on:      dozing-duly-7395
```

Do someone has an idea what's going wrong?

UPD:

```
''' Renders home page
'''
@login_required
def render_home(request):
    if not request.session.get('credentials', False):
        uri = util.refresh_credentials()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(uri)

    template = loader.get_template('templates/home.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {"username": request.user.username})

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))


''' Handle OAuth2 authorization
'''
def oauth_autorization(request):
    http_auth = util.authorize(request.GET['code'])
    request.session['credentials'] = http_auth.to_json()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auth:home'))
```

Here I'm dealing with OAuth2 Authorization, and I store my tokens in session, executing them each time when I need to send request to API

Comment: maybe you exceed those 20 when you run a script?.. Eg open page, try to allocate 21 connection, page fails, script aborts, no active sessions, so when you check you seeone - yours

Comment: I don't think that it is a reason. Actually it happens when I authorize in my app, so there are only a few possible interractions with database (authorize user, get session, save session).

Comment: can you read postgres.log in heroku?..

Comment: this is hobby-dev db, it doesn't support 'heroku logs'

Comment: yeah.. I see.. and can you post your code?.. how you call queries?..

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue right now. Yesterday everything was working without any problems. Wrote Heroku support - let's see what they say.

Comment: Updated topic with code samples. It''s pretty common code, and I don't think that its a code trouble

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is solved. I've written to Support, that was trouble from their side

Comment: I just created a new issue ticket here https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new . Sometimes there are troubles on their side. In my case they had server overload, so my application couldn't connect to the DB. On the next day, all became ok